# How to delete all keys that start with X from an object?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have an object:

```
test = {
"a":"aval",
"b":"bval",
"_c":"cval"
"d":"dval",
"_e":"eval"
}
```

I want to get rid of all that start with an "_". What is the simplest and most effective way to do this? Is this sort of an operation performance intensive? The result I want is:

```
test = {
"a":"aval",
"b":"bval",
"d":"dval"
}
```

Comment: Not very performance effective, but you can put a for loop to loop through all the keys, then get the first character of each key, then if it is an _, then delete it.

Comment: simple for in loop with indexOf/charAt check

Comment: I have 10,000 objects like that, but not every one has keys that include an "_". I am wishing for something that could be more effective than having to loop.

Comment: `for (var key in test) { if (key.indexOf("_") === 0) delete test[key] }`

Comment: Why all the downvotes. It is a good question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
for (var key in test) if (key.startsWith("_")) delete test[key];
```

Result:

```
Object {a: "aval", b: "bval", d: "dval"}
```

Comment: Does this build a new object or does this really modify the existing object?

Comment: it modifies the existing

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over all keys and check start char and after remove it

```js
var test = {
  "a":"aval",
  "b":"bval",
  "_c":"cval",
  "d":"dval",
  "_e":"eval"
};

Object.keys(test).forEach(function (key) {
  if (/^_/.test(key)) {
    delete test[key];
  }
});

console.log(test);
```